# How to get a single row result for data

Tags: mysql, join, mysql-8.0

I have the following two tables,

Table *Periods*,

```
Id  Names
1   Simon
2   Davis
```

Table *Tier*,

```
Id    sYear        days
1      0             0      
1      1             21     
1      5             30 
2      0             0      
2      1             26     
2      5             30
```

The table schema is not the best, but not much i can do about it.

I need to retrive the days for an id based on the following criteria,

- If sYear is 0 return 0
- If sYear is between 1 and 5 return 21, or 26 if it is id 2 in the above sample data
- if sYear is greater than 5 return 30

The ***days*** column values differ for the different id's but *sYear* is always 0,1 & 5.

My attempt looks like,

```
set @sYear = 7;

SELECT 
    et.id,
    names,
    CASE
        WHEN @sYear = 0 THEN days
        WHEN @sYear BETWEEN 1 AND 5 THEN days
        WHEN @sYear > 5 THEN days
    END as Result
FROM
    Periods ep
        JOIN
    Tier et ON (et.id = ep.id) AND et.id = 2;
```

which gives the results as,

```
id  names   Result
2   Davis    0
2   Davis    26
2   Davis    30
```

whereas the result required is,

```
id  names   Result
2   Davis   30
```

as *@sYear = 7* is greater than 5.

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=13f84d4a34d426a28ea08b7a9df35d01)

Comment: Why does every `WHEN` condition in your `CASE` statement evaluate to `days`?

Comment: because the days value is one of the required values that needs to be returned by the query

Comment: Then why not `SELECT et.id, names, days FROM ...`?

Comment: It will be much easier to understand what you are saying if you can use that dbfiddle link I put in the question. If it was not clear earlier that 7 is just an example, the value for @sYear could be anything. And et.id = 2 could be any Id as well.

Answer (score 0):

The following query will produce the results you can find in the tables:

@sYear = 7

| id | days | names |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 30 | Simon |
| 2 | 30 | Davis |

@sYear = 3

| id | days | names |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 21 | Simon |
| 2 | 26 | Davis |

@sYear = 0

| id | days | names |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | Simon |
| 2 | 0 | Davis |

```
SELECT 
    et.id, names, days as result 
FROM
    Tier et,
    Periods p
WHERE
    et.id = p.id
        AND et.days = (CASE
        WHEN @sYear = 0 THEN 0
        WHEN
            @sYear BETWEEN 1 AND 5 AND et.id = 2
        THEN
            (SELECT 
                    days
                FROM
                    Tier et
                WHERE
                    sYear = 1 AND et.id = 2)
        WHEN
            @sYear BETWEEN 1 AND 5 AND et.id = 1
        THEN
            (SELECT 
                    days
                FROM
                    Tier et
                WHERE
                    sYear = 1 AND et.id = 1)
        WHEN @sYear > 5 THEN 30
    END);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following query will produce exactly the result you defined in your question:

@sYear = 7

| id | names | result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Davis | 30 |

```
SELECT 
    et.id, names, days AS result
FROM
    Tier et,
    Periods p
WHERE
    et.id = p.id AND et.id = 2
        AND et.days = (CASE
        WHEN @sYear = 0 THEN 0
        WHEN
            @sYear BETWEEN 1 AND 5 AND et.id = 2
        THEN
            (SELECT 
                    days
                FROM
                    Tier et
                WHERE
                    sYear = 1 AND et.id = 2)
        WHEN
            @sYear BETWEEN 1 AND 5 AND et.id = 1
        THEN
            (SELECT 
                    days
                FROM
                    Tier et
                WHERE
                    sYear = 1 AND et.id = 1)
        WHEN @sYear > 5 THEN 30
    END);
```